# Pandas get consecutive rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to split a dataframe from pandas into multiple dataframes.

My dataframe has a column named 'C' with some rows containing a 0. What I hope to do is use the rows with 0's as a delimiter, so I get consecutive rows with values in the column 'C'. I don't think groupby is the way to go, as it takes the rows with the same values which isn't exactly what I'm trying to achieve unless I use it together with .diff() perhaps? I'm not sure. I feel I've tried so many things now, but Python and Pandas isn't my strongest language so I'm not sure what the possibilities are.

I have however managed to get it working using my own logic of for-loops and if-statements going through all the frames manually but it's a slow process and I hope to improve it.

**Before:**

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |

**After:**

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |

I am using Python if that isn't clear, any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create list of DataFrames:

```
#compare for equal 0
m = df['C'].eq(0)
#filter out 0 rows and grouping by cumulative sum of mask
dfs = [x for _, x in df[~m].groupby(m.cumsum())]
print (dfs)
[   A  C
0  1  4
1  2  5,    A  C
3  4  5
4  5  4
5  6  5]

print (dfs[1])
   A  C
3  4  5
4  5  4
5  6  5
```

Comment: Could you please explain "x for _x" and groupby(m.cumsum)? Am I right in understanding the latter only works if the index is 0,1,2,3 etc ?

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous - Sure, it is list comprehension and first groupnames are not important, so assigned to `_` and extract only `DataFrames` in variable `x`

Comment: Hi jezrael, thank you for responding!
I'm pretty limited in my characters available so I will keep it short. 
Why exactly are we using cumsum() to groupby? To my understanding cumsum() will cummulate all the values in a row as it goes through them. So how can it use that to put rows together.

Comment: @user15227672 - I use cumsum with mask `m = df['C'].eq(0)`, you can check `print (m)` and `print (m.cumsum())` how are created groups.

Comment: That makes sense yes! I see what it's doing now. Only cummulating values whenever the mask is True (meaning there's a zero) so that when C has a value it remains the same cummulated value and thus they will be grouped together. Thanks for your time.

Comment: the groupby has a index and values where _ , x represent a place holder and a value.  He could have put a variable for the place holder and returned the index value.  However, index is not needed in the solution

Comment: I don't understand how m.cumsum() created the two groups